# Как прочитать файл закодированный в кодировку utf-16 через python

Tags: python, python-3.x, кодировка

Как прочитать файл закодированный в кодировку utf-16 через python.
Вот код который я написал, но функции `.decode()` это не нравиться,
как сделать?

```
f=open(r"test.txt", "r").read()
print(f, f.decode('utf-16'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На входе имеем текстовый файл закодированный в "utf-16"

```
f = open(r"test.txt","rb").read()
print(f.decode('utf-16'))
```

Ваша ошибка в том что вы пытаетесь декодировать файл открытый в текстовом режиме

```
f = open(r"test.txt","r").read()
```

Если вы хотите декодировать файл открывайте в бинарном режиме

```
f = open(r"test.txt","rb").read()
```

Comment: Там ниже лучше ответ ;)

Comment: 0andriy я правильно ответил ;) с  тем ответом он так и не поймёт в чём его ошибка!

Comment: Такое впечатление складывается, что вы не понимаете в чём ошибка. Чем файл в UTF-16 не текстовый?

Comment: f=open(r"test.txt", "r").read()
print(f, f.decode('utf-16')) где вы видите здесь текстовый файл?            AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode' теперь объясните эту ошибку)

Comment: Я не понял, почему такой вопрос и почему он адресован мне. Вы же увидели сами там "текст", и он так и открывается. Но поскольку кодировка по умолчанию не 'utf-16', то само собой результат не тот, который ожидали. в соседнем ответе указано как правильно открывать тесктовые файлы.

Comment: Вопрос звучит так Как прочитать файл закодированный в кодировку utf-16 через python. Вот код который я написал, но функции .decode() это не нравиться, как сделать?  
f=open(r"test.txt", "r").read()
print(f, f.decode('utf-16'))                                                                        
я объяснил что  не нравиться   функции decode()  )))

Answer (score 1):

Просто при открытии файла явно указывайте кодировку:

```
f = open("test.txt", "r", encoding='utf-16')
print(f.read())
f.close()
```